# Is there any other way to see body of incoming message except using SMS_DELIVER_ACTION and SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION intent in Android?

Tags: android, security, android-intent, sms, message

I'm investigating security of message in Android.

Many people know how to see body of incoming message by SMS_DELIVER_ACTION or SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION intent..
(Of course, there are somethings different between Android 4.4(KitKat) and the previous Android version specially regarding message intents.)

Is there any other way for 3rd party apps to see body of incoming message except using SMS_DELIVER_ACTION or SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION intent in Android before the message is saved by message apps ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by intercept, exactly? Do you want to block incoming messages, or just be notified of their receipt?

Comment: Intercept means that 3rd party application can see incoming message body. I will change my question from 'intercept' to 'see'.

Comment: Sure, with a ContentObserver on the SMS Provider. It might not work everywhere, though.

Comment: But, I am wondering whether 3rd party application can see body of incoming message or not before message app saves body of incoming message. So, before the message is saved, any 3rd party app can see the body of incoming message without SMS_DELIVER_ACTION or SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION intents ?

Comment: Well, if you just want to "see" the message body, does it really matter in which order the apps receive them?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Mike. The order doesn't matter.(priority is not important.)

Comment: No problem. Yeah, the Intent actions you described, and querying the SMS Provider are pretty much the only ways SDK apps can read incoming messages.

Comment: so, Answer about my question is 'No' ? ............... my question : Is there any other way for 3rd party apps to see body of incoming message except using SMS_DELIVER_ACTION or SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION intent in Android before the message is saved by message apps ?

Comment: Those broadcasts are the only way an SDK app has to see messages _before_ any other app.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, Mike~